# How can I exclude a module from a minicpan repository?

Tags: perl, minicpan

I have a local MINICPAN repository, but I want to remove a specific version of a module, and inject an older version.

This is the steps I've taken.

```
- create the MINICPAN, not filtering any modules
- use mcpani --add for the module in question
- use mcpani --inject
```

At this point, I can see in the MINICPAN that it has both the version I want, and the newer version, if I issue install in cpan, then the newer version of the module is install. How can I get rid of the newer version from my minicpan?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filter the modules that you are going to inject. The [CPAN::Mini](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CPAN-Mini) has the documentation for filtering, and I think I had some examples in the resources I pointed you toward earlier. :)

If you already have the minicpan, as you said in the comment to ysth, you can create *another* minicpan from that one. The "remote" CPAN in that case is the one that you have. I do that all the time: I have a canonical minicpan, but then for testing things, I filter from that to create new repositories just so I don't have to deal with the network.

Comment: thanks again brian, and sorry for the cross post without notice.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't filtering out the module initially work?

Comment: it probably would, but once I have the repository locally, adding a filter doesn't seem to remove it.

I could delete the repository and start again with filtering, but that would take quite awhile.

Answer (score 0):

Another strategy would be to use [Pinto](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pinto).  Unlike a minicpan, a Pinto repository contains *only* the distributions you want (and their dependencies), so there is no need for filtering.  This results in a much smaller and more manageable pile of files, so you can easily do things like check it into your SCM.  Pinto also has some neat tools for handling upgrades without accidentally breaking your application.

Also, [Stratopan](https://stratopan.com) hosts Pinto repositories in the cloud.  You can manage the repository through your browser and install modules anywhere that has internet access.  It doesn't yet support all the features Pinto has, but Stratopan really takes the hassle out of maintaining a local CPAN.

*Disclaimer: I operate Stratopan.*